Where is there a source where shomer negia extends to non-Jews as well
BH
Hi I saw an article that Shomer Negia comes from "None of you shall come near anyone of his own flesh to uncover nakedness: I am the Lord” (18:6), and “Do not come near a woman during her period of uncleanness to uncover her nakedness” (18:19), although this is talking about coming close to someone who is a Jew. Where do we learn in the Torah that shomer negia extends to non-Jewish women as well?

“Although this is talking about coming close to someone who is a Jew” who said that?

BH
Doesn't don’t come near anyone of your own flesh also talk about niddah and isn’t it true that non Jewish woman don’t become nidah?
https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/shomer-negiah/

@CuriousYid no?

Those two sources don't cover even all of the arayos of Jews, but the principle and limud extends, as is common.
